Playwright is not locating data-testId
I'm using data-testid to locate a title entry field on a page. The input field has the tag "createTitle", however when I use the getByTestId method to locate it, the element cant be found and the test times out. Using VS codes ability to select a locator and selecting the field I'm trying to access, returns the suggestion to use:
locator('[data-testid="createTitle"]')

await test.step(`Input title as: ${title}`, async () => {
            
            // Failing solution
            await this.page.getByTestId("createTitle")

            // Passing solution
            await this.page.locator('[data-testid="createTitle"]')

            .fill(title)
        })

(obviously when I run the code I comment out one of the above solutions, I'm not trying to run both of them consecutively)
from my understanding of playwright, these tests should return exactly the same field as they should be locating the same tag, the tag is obviously accessible otherwise the second option would not work, so I don't understand why getbytestId is not working whatsoever.
The timeout error message given is:
Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded.

    Error: locator.fill: Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded.
    Call log:
      - waiting for getByTestId('createTitle')

I want to use the getByTestId method to access this page element to keep things consistent with other places in my code. This is the first instance I have had with this method not behaving properly

As a test, have you set the attribute testIdAttribute  to verify the attribute name is read correctly, in playwright.config.ts? I know the default value is data-testid but only to be sure. Which language do you use? For node, the structure is strange. A test should be test.describe('My tests', () => {test('verify things', async ({page}) => {         await do_somthing()         ....     })  }) A test doesn´t need await in front

@KlimBim I am using typescript, I think I have figured things out and it may be something to do with the strange structure you mentioned, this code snippet isnt where the test is executed but is a method in a page object module to be re-used. I had previously set a different object to a different attribute, but that should not have affected this specific part of my model as there is no inheritence between them. however, after removing this the tests started to work again. Not sure why this has happened but if you have any ideas I'd be glad to hear them

Is suspect that happened to your test and your super-test went missing?

@KlimBim Good call on the testIdAttribute, but you do need to await test.step().

await the action, not the locator. All locators need some sort of action or they do nothing (locators do not return promises):
await this.page.getByTestId("createTitle").waitFor();
//             ^-- declarative locator    ^-- action

You can also use an expect assertion, and you don't need to use .waitFor()--.fill() will work fine too if that's the action you want to take, as long as there's some action or other there. In fact, most things auto-wait, so waitFor is seldom necessary.
If you're in doubt regarding whether a call returns a promise, either check the docs or log it. If it doesn't return a promise, don't await it, otherwise do.
Beyond that, assuming you haven't overridden the default test id in your playwright.config.js file's testIdAttribute, both of your locators should work. Provide more reproduction details if this answer doesn't resolve the issue (show your full POM). Here's proof of correctness:
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.42.1

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
setTimeout(() => {
  document.body.innerHTML = '<input data-testid="createTitle">';
}, 2000);
</script>
</body>
</html>`;

test("some test", async ({page}) => {
  await test.step("element with test id 'createTitle' exists", async () => {
    await page.setContent(html);

    // either one works:
    // const input = page.locator('[data-testid="createTitle"]');
    const input = page.getByTestId("createTitle");

    await input.fill("foobar");
    await expect(input).toBeVisible(); // not really necessary
    await expect(input).toHaveValue("foobar");
  });
});

By the way, the purpose of a POM is to separate locators from actions and assertions. Locators should be defined in the POM constructor, actions in POM action methods, assertions in main-line test cases. In general, there should not be assertions in the POM, and there should not be locators in POM action methods. So you may have other antipatterns in your design.

Thanks for your answer, I have fixed the issue but am interested in your comment about the POM, is there a particular reason for having it setup like this, it seems to me that having the locator in the method cuts down on lines of code, a locator will always be linked to a specficic action (for example retrieving the location of a button will always involve clicking that button as the next step) so why not just store the locator with that action in the method rather than constructing it and then referencing it. Please let me know if there's something I am missing

When you say "I have fixed the issue", did you fix the issue using my answer, or something else? If something else, please post a self answer and clarify your question to help future visitors so they know what you did exactly.

As for the POM, see the Playwright docs example. All locators are in the constructor, and all actions are in methods. If a locator is always tied to one action, you should still declare it once in the constructor for two reasons: (1) all locators are defined in one place in the constructor so you don't have to hunt around for them (if it's duplicated, you'd have to remember to change all of them if the locator needs to change--harder to maintain) and (2) you can reuse that locator in multiple action methods even if it's always the same action.

The POM itself is simply a grouping of higher-level locators and actions for a page or view in your website, and within the POM, the locators and actions are organized separately. You can supplement that with generic utility classes that handle common tasks for multiple pages. All assertions are in test cases. Usually this is the perfect level of abstraction for most testing scenarios. Problems arise when people start putting assertions in random helper functions, passing pages/locators around through nested func calls, defining locators in random places, adding helper class hierarchies, etc.
